# Deleting iPad Analytics Data

Tags: ios, ipad, privacy

I was checking my Privacy settings after updating my iPad (I wanted to make sure Apple didn't "helpfully" reset them), and I noticed a large number of saved Analytics Data files.

I *don't* want to send them in, I just want to delete them. Is there any way to do this without resetting the entire device?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have ever been able to delete diagnostic data or analytics is to sync with iTunes (physically tethered to usb port not over wifi) and in iTunes select clear warnings then sync. Sometimes it takes several attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Sync your ipad to a pc via usb port your device will remove all diagnostic data this takes a couple minutes once complete check your ipad it should be clear.